How to resolve cx_Freeze error about pdf2docx mupdf import?
I've never posted here before, but this time I'm genuinely stuck. I'm using cx_Freeze on a python script that uses pdf2docx. Running the python script normally works fine, but running cx_Freeze's executable gives this error:
Unhandled exception: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, No module named 'mupdf'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\truma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymupdf\__init__.py", line 193, in <module>
    from . import mupdf
ImportError: cannot import name 'mupdf' from partially initialized module 'pymupdf' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\truma\Documents\ballotreaderclone\ballotreader\resources\build\exe.win-amd64-3.12\lib\pymupdf\__init__.pyc)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ballots.py", line 1149, in startInitUI
  File "C:\Users\truma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "ballots.py", line 1155, in initUI
  File "ballots.py", line 23, in runOtherInit
  File "C:\Users\truma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pdf2docx\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .converter import Converter
  File "C:\Users\truma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pdf2docx\converter.py", line 9, in <module>
    import fitz
  File "C:\Users\truma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\fitz\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pymupdf import *
  File "C:\Users\truma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pymupdf\__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    import mupdf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mupdf'

I've tried every suggestion chatgpt had, but nothing worked.
From my analysis it seems like cx_Freeze is messing up the order of imports in all the different python files, and ends up tying itself in a knot that it can't get out of... or something.
Yes, I've tried installing mupdf. It doesn't look like mupdf is supported for python 3 anymore though.
I've also tried reinstalling pdf2docx, pymupdf, and pip.
Edit: my program needs to convert pdfs to docs en mass, and pdf2docx was the fastest package I found. If there's another package that's faster... I guess I could use that instead?
Edit 2: Tried using Nuitka. The error output is similar.
C:\Users\truma\Documents\ballotreaderclone\ballotreader\resources>python -m nuitka ballots.py --standalone
Nuitka-Options: Used command line options: ballots.py --standalone
Nuitka: Starting Python compilation with Nuitka '2.3.11' on Python '3.12' commercial
Nuitka: grade 'not installed'.
Nuitka-Plugins:WARNING: Use '--enable-plugin=pyqt5' for: Inclusion of Qt plugins.
Nuitka: Interrupted while working on '<Node 'COMPILED_PYTHON_MODULE' with {'filename':
Nuitka: 'C:\\Users\\truma\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\pymupdf\\mupdf.py',
Nuitka: 'module_name': <ModuleName 'pymupdf.mupdf'>, 'code_flags': ''}>'.
PASS 1: 95.2%|███████████████████████▊ | 713/749, pymupdf.mupdf

It basically just gets stuck on this. I ran it for at least an hour and a half, with it being stuck on this package for basically all of that time.

May I suggest to use Nuitka instead of cxfreeze? It is more stable and faster. Also, the Python code is converted to C and cannot be recovered as you could do it with the *.pyc files that cxfreeze stores. If I remember right, then also only actually used packages are included in the distro - not everything for which there exist an import somewhere in the source code.

@JorjMcKie just tried that. See the edit

Hm, too bad. Sorry it doesn't work ...
